# What is a good self-study probability book that isn't TOO difficult

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, self-learning

I've spent a lot of time with Blitzstein & Hwang Introduction to Probability as well as Bertsekas Introduction to Probability, but I find the end of chapter problems are just too difficult for me to stay motivated. I need something a bit more approachable, where it doesn't feel like every single practice problem is lifting the weight of the world.

Are there any good books you'd recommend with slightly easier practice problems?

Comment: Schilling - Measurs, Integrals and Martingales

Comment: @EnricoM. OP is likely looking for an undergrad level text (non-measure-theoretic).

Comment: @angryavian Oh, maybe in this case then Feller's book could be more suitable? Or Gnedenko's Theory of Probability maybe

Answer (score 1):

The book that was used at my undergraduate institution for probability was the book [Basic Probability Theory](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf), which is made freely available online by the author. As the book states in the preface:

> This book has been written for a first course in probability[...] The only formal prerequisite is calculus, but an additional degree of mathematical maturity may be helpful.

The author also tries to point out measure-theoretic ideas "while emphasizing the probabilistic way of thinking." The book does not use formal measure theory at all.